# How can I add Magick++ to Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator, magick++

Good day. I am trying to set up my Qt Creator to use Magick++. I've added

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-23/include/ImageMagick-7
```

And that sort of worked, I can now add

```
#include <Magick++.h>
```

It does autocomplete and everything. But I get a lot of warnings that I am supposed to set MAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH and MAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE to sensible values. I have no idea what it is and how to do it. I've tried to research this topic but only found that I need to add Lib files like this:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $(shell Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags)
LIBS += $(shell Magick++-config --ldflags --libs)
```

but that only added an error: :-1: error: Magick++-config: Command not found

I am using the latest version of Qt creator. ImageMagick-7. Mac OSX Mojave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `MAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH` & `MAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE` must be added to qmake's [`DEFINES` variable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#defines).

Try the following...

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $(shell Magick++-config --cxxflags)
LIBS += $(shell Magick++-config --libs)
DEFINES += "MAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16"
DEFINES += "MAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1"
```

... assuming you are running ImageMagick-7 Q16 HDRI library.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That gets rid of warnings< but I am still getting this: Magick++-config: Command not found error

Comment: Try using a the absolute path to the config utility. On my mac, that would be `$(shell /usr/local/bin/Magick++-config --cxxflags)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are amazing.